# Setting the attribute of an object to be and attribute of another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes

Im very new to Ruby on rails. I am trying to set a Product object (:userid) to  the user object id (user.id). So far I have got this

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_userid
  def set_userid
    self.userid = User.new(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Is there any other way to set the value before the product object is created?

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain what you are trying to achieve (in english, not in code)?  The code you have here has a lot of issues and so it's hard to advise you on what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Consider using associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)
to easily define relations between models using helpers like

```
Product    
belongs_to :user

User
has_many :products
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't works because model doesn't have access to `params`. So, you should assign User instance in action of your controller:

```
def your_action
  ...
  product = ...
  product.user = User.new(params[:id])
```